# Dynamic nested loops over array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically doing a deep looping over an array.
Lets say i have a function that takes an `array` of numbers and a `total` number, it will loop over the array and will return a tuple of the numbers that together make the sum of the total:

```
const sumOfTwo = (arr, total) => {
  let map = {};

  for (let currentNum of arr) {
    if (map[currentNum] !== undefined) {
      return [map[currentNum], currentNum]
    } else {
      map[total - currentNum] = currentNum;
    }
  }
  return [];
}

const num = 6
const arr = [4, 5, 2, 3, 1];
const result = sumOfTwo(arr, num);
console.log(result); // [4, 2]
```

Now if i want to create the same function but that finds a sum of three numbers, i will have to do a nested loop:

```
function sumOfThree(arr, total) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let processed = {};
    let firstNum = arr[i];
    let firstDelta = total - firstNum;
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
      let secondNum = arr[j];
      let secondDelta = firstDelta - secondNum;
      if (processed[secondDelta]) {
        return [firstNum, secondNum, secondDelta];
      }
      processed[secondNum] = true;
    }
  }
  return [];
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const sum = 6;
const result = sumOfThree(arr, sum);
console.log(result); // [1, 3, 2]
```

If i want a `sumOfFour` function, i guess i need another nested loop and so on.

What i actually want is to create a generic function `sumOf` that will take the `array`, the `total` but also that number of `numbers` it should add up to the `total`. I was thinking of doing a recursive flow but got stuck on the very first line, now i'm not so sure it can be done.

Any suggestion would be much appropriated

Comment: The simplest solution to this is to use lodash `._sum` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generators are really useful then to yield values up, also you can pass down the previous sum and values through the recursion:

```
function* sumUp(values, target, n, previous = [], sum = 0) {
  // Base case: if the combination of n values is target, yield it, or exit
  if(n <= 0) {
    if(sum === target) yield previous;
    return;
  }

  // otherwise add this combo
  for(const value of values) {
    // don't use the same number twice
    if(previous.includes(value)) continue;

    yield* sumUp(values, target, n - 1, [...previous, value], sum + value);       
  }
}
```

Usable as:

```
  // all combinations
 console.log([...sumUp([1, 2, 3, 4], 7, 2)]);
 // just the first
 console.log(sumUp([1, 2, 3, 4], 7, 2).next().value);
```

Comment: Thank you! 2 problems though, 1) not sure i can use generators in my project, so i was looking for a regular function solution. 2) the numbers cannot get repeated, i mean if `n` is 4 it will yield `[1, 1, 1, 4]`. in this case i would like to get an empty array, same as my example above.

Comment: @jasDotnet 2) edited, 1) replace `yield` with `return` and `yield*` with `const v = /*...*/; if(v) return v;`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! will examine the code to understand it better